# How do I use a score in a different command in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am making a game where a player has a score that goes up every second by a different stat. That stat is their score on a specific scoreboard. How do I do this?

For Example,
If their score for the stat is 26, every second a their other score goes up by 26

Thanks

P.S. Also, can I make that score be the name for an armor stand?

Comment: So you want to do this with a command block?

Comment: Take a look at "/scoreboard players operation", more information here: http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Scoreboard#Command_reference

Comment: yeah, a command block. And i get how to use scoreboard, i just dont know the syntax for something like /scoreboard players add objective -score from other objective-

Comment: i meant /scoreboard players add @p objective -score from other objective-

Comment: @ShurikenNinja95 Just to clarify: I mentioned "/scoreboard players *operation* " explicitly in the comment to nudge you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For Example, If their score for the stat is 26, every second a their other score goes up by 26

I'll use `MainScore` for "their other score", and `Increment` for "score for the stat".

---

The command you want is:

```
/execute @a ~ ~ ~ /scoreboard players operation @a[c=1] MainScore += @a[c=1] Increment
```

This makes each player add their `Increment` to their `MainScore`.